# Access Canvas RGB Data and Assemble Image in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, rgb

I need to be able to access a canvas' imagedata, however it's stored in some kind of array (UINT8 or something) that prevents me from accessing the data. Specifically, I need to get the RGB data of the entire canvas.

Assuming that can be done, how could I (in PHP) reconstruct the canvas image properly from the RGB data array? The browser this application is for lacks "toDataURL()", so I'd prefer to accomplish this as specified please.

Comment: I dont quite know what you are trying to do but I'm guessing you're going to want `Canvas.getImageData()` in your JS. That will give you the RGBA data.

Comment: @andbeyond I'm trying to use the RGB data from getImageData() and have PHP recreate the image, but I can't access the data because it's in a weird array.

Comment: Have you tried json encoding the image data before sending it to a php script? If not, try that first.